# Jest and travis CI, "SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word"

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, jestjs

I have written an npm module which I'm trying to use with Travis CI.  My tests were written in Jest and all pass when I run them from my local command line.

However, when I upload them to github (https://github.com/jaysaurus/echo-handler), travis runs my code and spits the following exception:

```
0.69s$ npm test

> echo-handler@1.1.2 test /home/travis/build/jaysaurus/echo-handler

> jest __tests__/*.js

/home/travis/build/jaysaurus/echo-handler/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:1

sModule", { value: true });exports.runCLI = exports.run = undefined;let run = 

                                                                ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/jaysaurus/echo-handler/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:13:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I wondered if my build was looking in the /node_modules by accident. .gitignore has been set up to ignore /node_modules and I even tried setting my package.json to explicitly run: `"test": "jest __tests__/*.js",` but I still get the same error

is this a bug in jest/the version of jest on Travis CI/Travis CI's implementation of jest? If so, is there a workaround? Alternatively (and far more likely) have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified a Node.js version in your [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/jaysaurus/echo-handler/blob/8c4e5029cf550fb6777acc51f8610a015d0c5ed2/.travis.yml) and it appears that it has [installed version `0.10.48`](https://travis-ci.org/jaysaurus/echo-handler/builds/288536977#L434). Back then `let` was not supported and it threw an error when you tried to use one of such reserved words (at least in strict mode).

You should always [specify the Node.js versions](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Specifying-Node.js-versions)  you want to run it on.

For example if you want to only run it on the latest `8.x` version, you would use the following configuration:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8"
```